# Data frame writes to a single column in write.csv/write.table R

Tags: r, export, export-to-csv

I'm trying to write a csv file (I would use write.xlsx, but for some reason that was giving me Java memory errors.... no matter, I'll do this instead), but if I used the following data frame:

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
email <- c('jim@chase.com','steve@aol.com','stacy@gmail.com/','chris@yahoo.com','emilio@verizon.net/')
sample <- data.frame(id,email)
write.table(sample, 'Me\\Raw List.csv',
           row.names = TRUE, col.names = TRUE, append = FALSE)
```

I get the data all in a single-column CSV, along with a row identifier like this:

```
id "email"
1 1 "jim@chase.com"
2 2 "steve@aol.com"
3 3 "stacy@gmail.com/"
4 4 "chris@yahoo.com"
5 5 "emilio@verizon.net/"
```

My question is two-part: 1) How do I separate this data into columns; and 2) How do I remove the row identifiers so that I can just use my `id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`write.table()`'s standard separator is " " (check the docs). 
Use `write.csv()` or `write.csv2()` along with the parameter `row.names=False` instead.

```
write.csv(sample,file = "my_dir/my_file.csv", row.names=F)
```

`row.names=F` makes that a unique row identifier (basically an id like you have it) will not be written.

You may use `write.table()` as well but you'll have to pass additional parameters:

```
write.table(sample, file = "test.csv", row.names=F, sep=",", dec=".")
```